# CSS - Margin Padding HTML

Tags: html, css

¿Por qué no me respeta la linea blanca entre el primer y segundo elemento?
Os dejo mi web: http://www.osmarentcars.esy.es/

El CSS es:

```
*{
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}


#todo{
    width: 750px;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 14;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}


div{
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}


img{
    float: left;
    width: 96px;
    height: 60px;
}


.columna{
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}


.descripcion{
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el html también?

Comment: Sí, no lo puse porque es bastante largo, ya que genero el HTML gracias a una consulta en JAVA con datos de MySQL. Os dejo el link del HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/omaza1990/psrekxv5/

Comment: tienes un `div` llamado `#todo` con 100px de altura y el mismo color azul de fondo que las cajas, está tapando el margen entre las dos primeras

Comment: @blonfu Es la respuesta correcta. Con `#todo{ background: transparent }` se arregla

Comment: @blonfu Te recomiendo que lo agregues como respuesta para poder cerrar esta pregunta y que el OP la acepte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás poniendo el fondo azul a todos los `div` de tu página y supongo que eso no te interesara cuando tu código sea más complejo. El caso es que tienes un `div#todo` que engloba a los demás y tiene una altura de 100px que es algo más que el tamaño de la primera caja por lo que su fondo azul tapa el espacio entre ese `div` y el siguiente.

Puedes poner solo el color a los div que te interesan, una opción podría ser:

```
#todo > div {
    background-color: #0FF;
}
```

Tampoco tiene mucho sentido que el `div#todo` tenga una altura, puedes borrarla.

**PD:** Deberías copiar el código en tu pregunta con la opción de fragmento de código ya que si corriges la web que has enlazado dejan de tener sentido la pregunta y las respuestas y no servirá a nadie más.

Comment: Sigo con el mismo problema.

Comment: Pensaba que estaba solucionado, marcaste la respuesta como aceptada. ¿Qué ha ocurrido ahora?

Answer (score 1):

La solucion de @blonfu es correcta, simplemente quiero explicarte como hacerlo mejor y mas facil de mantener.

1. El `<div id="todo">` no le des altura fija (ya se que ya se dijo). Es un contenedor de un listado por lo que es mejor que se expanda por si solo.
2. A cada uno de los "renglones" de la lista, ponles una clase: `<div class="elemento">` y luego dale estilo a todos los elementos de la lista usando dicha clase en CSS. De esta forma agrupas todas las propiedades del renglon en la clase y no se mezclan entre otros elementos existentes o futuros de la pagina.

Ejemplo:

```
.elemento {
   background: color;
   margin-top: 4px;
 }
```

Comment: Sí, también puede ser buena idea darles clases a los elementos

Comment: Funcionan ambas ideas pero a la hora de generar el index.html y subirlo a ftp me da el mismo error. http://osmarentcars.esy.es/

Comment: Lo que sí me funciona es desde el local, cuando genero el index.html y lo genero en el local file:// sí funciona... pero cuando voy al navegador, me sale desconfigurado el css.

Comment: Sigo con el mismo problema... no sé a que se debe. Ni poniendo al div en cuestión la propiedad: background